# Express res Status Code 200 but return content is not complete

Tags: node.js, http, express, pug, response

Query 3000 items data from mongodb, then the express res.render the jade templet, but the page content is not complete.

Really weird!

On my local mac air, everything seems fine. Then on my centos server, I visit the page, never get the entire page content.

```
"express": "^4.10.1",
"jade": "^1.3.1"

Node.js version: 0.10.21
Nginx   version: 1.4.3
```

In the controller:

```
User
  .find({})
  .sort({'meta.createdAt': -1})
  .exec(function(err, results) {
    res.render('page', {
      results: results
    })
  })
```

I am pretty sure it's not the nginx's problem but the Node or Express. Because
 I query the 3000 items, then write it into a json file whenever the content is requested from the browser, the nginx handles the json file and return correctly.

Wish somebody could help me figure out what happened.

Comment: Did you try without nginx to see if it still occurs? That might help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Because everything is handled via nginx, and same with the https. All the certificate and keys are configured in the nginx config file. Turn nginx down means the website will not be accessable. @mscdex